# How to delete the first and last two characters from a text file using sed?

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, string-parsing

I have a text file like this

```
abcdefg
abcdefg
abcdefg
abcdefg
```

How to delete the first and last two characters from each line with sed? I would like to get the output like this

```
bcde
bcde
bcde
bcde
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed  's/^.\(.*\)..$/\1/'  file
```

Comment: note: this won't work if the string has less than 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/^.\|..$//g' file
```